# Postgres - using `on conflict do update`, return if the action was an insert or update

Tags: postgresql

Im using the `on conflict` clause of Postgresql to achieve something like an "upsert", like this:

```
INSERT INTO person (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'alice')
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET name = 'alice'
RETURNING id;
```

the table looks like this

```
 CREATE TABLE person (id serial primary key, name text not null);
```

I now would like to know when i execute the above insert query, whether it was performed as an insert or an update.

Is there a way to return something like this:

```
...
RETURNING id, no_conflict_insert
```